# Zebra Technologies ZTC GC420t ZPL blank printing

Tags: java, ubuntu, zpl

Trying to send ZPL to GC420t but printing only Blank label. Following options tried,

1) Through CUPS:
[Zebra Printing with CUPS no print ZPL or EPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501974/zebra-printing-with-cups-no-print-zpl-or-epl)
  - Empty label

2)cat label.zpl > /dev/usb/lp0

OS - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
CUPS
ZPL

```
^XA
^PW950
^CI28
^LH10,10
^FO300,45^A0N,20,20^FDChuridar piece^FS
^FO300,65^A0N,10,10^FD^FS
^FO340,65^A0N,20,20^FD235.0^FS
^BY2,3.0^FO300,85^BEN,60,Y,N^FD1111111113882^FS
^JUR
^XZ
```

Our application is Java and face same issue. Surprisingly it works from Python CUPS.

Please help to work directly from Unix or Java.